# How can i write this as one query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a model called Shop and one called Brand.

```
shop :has_many_brands
brands: belongs_to_shop
```

What i want to do is have one query that does the following.
Select all shops and brands.
Show a list of all shops, first show shops that has brands ordered by shop.name and then show the rest off the shops ordered by shop.name.

Hope it makes sense...

Is that possible?

Comment: You want a list of all shops only if they have a brand. If they don't have a brand, you wish to display them after the shops with brands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need a listing in the view, the easiest way to do this would be to display one, then the other.

So you'll display all the shops with brands, and sort normally.

Then display all shops without brands, and sort normally.

In your shop show controller:

```
if Shop.brands.empty?
   @shopsWithout = @shops.sort_by{ |shop| shop.name}
else
   @shopsWith = @shops.sort_by{ |shop| topic.name}
end
```

then in your view, just display each.

```
<% unless @shopsWith.blank?  %>
  <% @shopsWith.each do |shop| %>
    Shop: <%= shop.name %> Brand: <%= (you can loop shop.brands.all) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<% unless @shopsWithout.blank? %>
  <% @shopsWithout.each do |shop| %>
    Shop: <%= shop.name %><br />
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I tested this and it works fine. Not sure how to concatenate @shopsWith and @shopsWithout, but if you can do that in the controller (@shops = @shopsWith << @shopsWithout) then you only need one loop. I wasn't able to figure that out without Ruby thinking I'm using an array instead of a collection of objects.